# Consulta Mysql con laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Soy nuevo con laravel y me encuentro desarrollando un aplicativo login sin embargo los validadores de acceso no son los tipicos email y password. Mi pregunta es como puedo ejecutar la siguiente consulta Mysql en Laravel:

SELECT
    *
FROM
    `BD`.`tabla1`,`BD`.`tabla2`
WHERE
    `documento` = 123456
AND
    `tipo_id` = 4
AND
`tabla2`.`id` = 00001

La consulta la ejecutaria en el loginController luego de que el usuario pasa los datos

Comment: Bienvenido por favor muéstranos que has hecho

Comment: Hasta ahora solo tengo la funcion login con el validador de los datos ingresador por el usuario: $credentials= $this->validate(request(), [
  'nroservicio' => 'required|string',
  'voucher' => 'required|string'


 ]); Se que las consultas en tablas se ejecutan con $query = DB::table(tabla 1) pero en mi caso las consultas las hago en mas de una tabla. No quisiera usar join porque el query mostrado inicialmente me funciona perfectamente en la BD

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega ese código en la pregunta. Revisa [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
$data= \DB::table('tabla1')
    ->select('tabla1.*', 'tabla2.id as id_tabla2')
    ->join('tabla2', 'tabla2.id', '=', 00001)
    ->where('tabla1.documento', 123456)
    ->where('tabla1.tipo_id', 4)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, el query que indicas me funciona a nivel de bd sin embargo me arroja el siguiente error en laravel: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '6' in 'on clause' (42S22). 6 es el id de la tabla

Comment: Ese problema suele pasar cuando la primary key es distinta a `id`, ya que laravel asume que la llave primaria se llame id.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he leido que para solventar esto debo reemplazar el nombre de la llave foranea en el modelo sin embargo esta bd no puede ser modificada, y no tengo un modelo para esta tabla